# vba split(string, "\\"" Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert longitude and latitude in format `a b' c"` to degrees. To solve this problem I tried to use `split(string1, "\\"")` but does not help. 
How do I split a string using `"` as a delimiter.

Thanks

Comment: Bad news: VBA doesn't know how to escape characters using "\". Good news: You have good answers by Siddarth Rout and Kamil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You escaping `"` wrong.

Try this: `split(string1, """")`

---

Some documentation: [String Data Type (Visual Basic) at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx)

I know thats VB, not VBA, but language fundamentals are (almost?) identical.

Comment: + 1 Yup. Straight and simple :)

Answer (score 8):

Another way

```
Split(string1, Chr(34))
```